# Redirection according to the user group after login

Tags: django, logging, group-by, redirect

I would like to create a redirection of the user after login in function of the group.
I have two groups A and B in my admin.
Redirect link for group A: / add_name /
Redirect link for group B: / validate_name /

I have already done this in my ***settings.py:***  **LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "validate_name"**.
But by doing this, all the users write on the same link.

What is the right way to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single view that will handle your redirections.

```
@login_required
def redirect_view(request):
   # add checks as per your model relation, This is just an idea
   user_groups = list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))

   if 'A' in user_groups:
      return redirect(reverse('add_name')) 
   else:
      return redirect(reverse('validate_name'))
```

Bind this view in **urls.py**

```
 url(r'^redirect_view/$', redirect_view, name='redirect_view')
```

Now in **settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "redirect_view"
```